# How to build and start next.JS in production with graphql appollo server?

Tags: node.js, graphql, next.js, apollo-client

I am trying to dockerize a next.JS TypeScript app which uses express and apollo graphql.

My server/index.ts looks like this:

```
app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express.default();

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  });

  server.get("*", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  apolloServer.start().then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    const graphqlHandler = apolloServer.createHandler({ path: "/" });
    server.use("/api/graphql", graphqlHandler);
    server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, (err: string | void) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(
        `>>> Listening on http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`
      );
    });
  });
});
```

apollo client:

```
const GRAPHQL_URL = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ?  'http://localhost:3000/api/graphql': 'https://app1.com/api/graphql'  ;
```

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
          "build:next": "next build",
          "build": "npm run build:next && npm run build:server",
          "start": "next start",
          "start:production": "node dist/index.js"
```

If building with `npm run build` and then `npm run start:production`, then after the first refresh I get the error ``` ReferenceError: Cannot access 'data' before initialization ````. In this case the query request is on the **CSR** and not with **getServerSideProps**. The environment variable here is still "development" and not "production".

If building with `next build` and `next start` then my appollo server does not start and I get a *404* that the graphql API is not found.

I am starting the app in production in a docker container:

```
FROM node:16

ENV PORT 3000

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Installing dependencies
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Copying source files
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Building app
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000

# Running the app
ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "start:production" ]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: _"The environment variable here is still "development" and not "production""_ - Update your `start:production` script to `NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server.